# Connect two USB-C displays to MacBook Pro 15" 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, screen

is it even possible to connect two USB-C displays to one MacBook Pro 15" 2018?

Seems like MacOS intentionally shuts down one of them. I'm a bit puzzled why..

Comment: Yes. You can connect up to 4. Please describe the exact scenario in detail so we can try to drill down to the actual cause. Also mention if you are using any kind of adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should absolutely be able to do this. From [Apple's web site](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP776?locale=en_US)

> Video Support
>
> Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display at millions of colors and:
>
> Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
>      Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
>
> Thunderbolt 3 digital video output
>
> Native DisplayPort output over USB‑C
>      VGA, HDMI, DVI, and Thunderbolt 2 output supported using adapters (sold separately)

However USB-C/Thunderbolt can be a bit finicky/picky about cables and monitors. Perhaps if you shared your exact configuration (cables/lengths, monitors, etc.) we might be able to help. Just add that info to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Steve Chambers for pointers. What I had to do: just change changed resolution using "scaled resolution" selector for one of external screens and it worked for me. Now both external displays show image. I don't know why, but it worked.

Comment: It would be great if you accepted my post as an official answer, glad it worked for you!